Relatedness Matrix how to add subjects automatically
I have a relatedness matrix like this one:
data <- (c(1,1,0.01,0.02,0.03,0.06,
           1,1,0.01,0.02,0.03,0.06,
           0.01,0.01,1,0.5,0.03,0.02,
           0.02,0.02,0.5,1,0.02,0.03,
           0.03,0.03,0.03,0.02,1,0.03,
           0.06,0.06,0.02,0.03,0.03,1))


Matrix <- matrix(data, ncol = 6,nrow=6,  byrow = FALSE) # byrow = FALSE por defecto


row.names(Matrix) <- (c("1A", "1B", "2A", "2B", "3A", "3B"))
colnames(Matrix) <- (c("1A", "1B", "2A", "2B", "3A", "3B"))

Matrix
     1A   1B   2A   2B   3A   3B
1A 1.00 1.00 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.06
1B 1.00 1.00 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.06
2A 0.01 0.01 1.00 0.50 0.03 0.02
2B 0.02 0.02 0.50 1.00 0.02 0.03
3A 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.02 1.00 0.03
3B 0.06 0.06 0.02 0.03 0.03 1.00

So it gives the association of each subject with the rest of subjects.
I need to "duplicate" some subjects (they have the same patern of association with the rest of the sample). So, in this example I would like to duplicate participant 3B and name it as 3C. Here the expected output:
data2 <- (c(1,1,0.01,0.02,0.03,0.06,0.06,
           1,1,0.01,0.02,0.03,0.06,0.06,
           0.01,0.01,1,0.5,0.03,0.02,0.02,
           0.02,0.02,0.5,1,0.02,0.03,0.03,
           0.03,0.03,0.03,0.02,1,0.03,0.03,
           0.06,0.06,0.02,0.03,0.03,1,1,
           0.06,0.06,0.02,0.03,0.03,1,1))


Matrix2 <- matrix(data2, ncol = 7,nrow=7,  byrow = FALSE) # byrow = FALSE por defecto


row.names(Matrix2) <- (c("1A", "1B", "2A", "2B", "3A", "3B", "3C"))
colnames(Matrix2) <- (c("1A", "1B", "2A", "2B", "3A", "3B", "3C"))

 Matrix2
     1A   1B   2A   2B   3A   3B   3C
1A 1.00 1.00 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.06 0.06
1B 1.00 1.00 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.06 0.06
2A 0.01 0.01 1.00 0.50 0.03 0.02 0.02
2B 0.02 0.02 0.50 1.00 0.02 0.03 0.03
3A 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.02 1.00 0.03 0.03
3B 0.06 0.06 0.02 0.03 0.03 1.00 1.00
3C 0.06 0.06 0.02 0.03 0.03 1.00 1.00

Would it be possible to do that automatically?
Thank you so much in advance

You can write a little helper function
dup_sample <-function(m, existing, new_name) {
  stopifnot(existing %in% rownames(m) & existing %in% colnames(m))
  row <- m[existing, ]
  col <- m[, existing]
  newm <- rbind(cbind(m, row), c(col, 1))
  dimnames(newm) <- list(c(rownames(m), new_name), c(colnames(m), new_name))
  newm
}

Then you can all it with
dup_sample(Matrix, "3B", "3C")
#      1A   1B   2A   2B   3A   3B   3C
# 1A 1.00 1.00 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.06 0.06
# 1B 1.00 1.00 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.06 0.06
# 2A 0.01 0.01 1.00 0.50 0.03 0.02 0.02
# 2B 0.02 0.02 0.50 1.00 0.02 0.03 0.03
# 3A 0.03 0.03 0.03 0.02 1.00 0.03 0.03
# 3B 0.06 0.06 0.02 0.03 0.03 1.00 1.00
# 3C 0.06 0.06 0.02 0.03 0.03 1.00 1.00


That is amazing! Thank you so much!How can I do that for a list of participants automatically (e.g. 1A, 2B...). My problem is that I need to duplicate sometimes the A subject and sometimes the B subject (imagine that in the example you have 1A 2B and 3A and you need to create 1B, 2A and 3B). Should I use a loop?
